# how to pass php variable to jquery tooltip using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have `event_id` php variable in current page. and I want to display it in jquery tooltip using ajax(must). But there's error that `event_id` isn't defined

jquery file which has tooltip function:

```js
function tooltip(self){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("tr").tooltip({
            track: true,
            content: function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: window.location.pathname,//current url
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {event_id}, //undefined
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tooltip_td').attr('title', data); 
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $("tr").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).attr('title','Please wait...');
            $(this).tooltip();
            $('.ui-tooltip').hide();
        });
    });
}
```

index.blade.php: // I call tooltip function in this html file.
                // $participant has event_id

```html
            <tr>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $participant['id'] }}</td>
                 <td class="can_filter" id="tooltip_td" data-js="{{ $participant['event_id'] }}" title="Any default tooltip title" onclick="
                    tooltip(this);
                ">{{ $participant['name'] }}</td>
```

what should I have to do? Thank in advance!

Comment: That's because you've not defined `event_id` anywhere in your JS, or given it a value...?

Comment: Yes so what I want to do is to pass `event_id` in index.blade.php to jquery file : )
and display it in tooltip

Comment: you have used data-js .. i think you might wanna change {event_id} to something $(this).data('js')

Comment: oh I've never seen that before. You mean like this? `content: function(){
                $event_id = $('#tooltip_td').attr('data-js');
                $.ajax({
                    url: window.location.pathname,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {event_id}, ...`?

Answer (score 1):

you can init "event_id" in jquery like this:

```
var eventID = $(this).data('js');
```

and then use eventID in data object. like this:

```
$.ajax({
         url: window.location.pathname,//current url
         type: 'post',
         data: {'event_id':eventID},
         success: function(data){
            $('#tooltip_td').attr('title', data); 
         }
});
```

good luck [ ai ]